# Вывести объект(abcobjects)

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Как вывести объект с помощью модуля ABCObject?
Вот, ниже я привёл программу для создания объекта.
И есть какая-нибудь функция, позволяющая определить координаты объекта?

```
uses abcobjects,graphabc;
var
i:circleabc;
begin
  i:=circleabc.create(150,150,15,clyellow);
end.
```

Укажите, пожалуйста, источники информации, из которых можно узнать о модуле graphabc.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически, создав экземпляр класса (объект) через конструктор `Create`, вы его "вывели" на канву с заданными координатами (150,150), радиусом 15 и цветом clYellow (не стесняйтесь навести курсор и затем нажать F1 в IDE - выведется справка на русском по данному классу).
Дальше вы можете обращаться к свойствам объекта и использовать их. Например:

```
uses abcobjects,graphabc;
var
i:circleabc;
s:string;
begin
  i := circleabc.create(150,150,15,clyellow); 
// создаём закрашенный жёлтый круг с координатами 150, 150, радиусом 15
  s:='X: '+ i.Left.ToString+' '+' Y: ' +i.Top.ToString+' Radius: '+ i.Radius;
// запрашиваем его свойства: координаты (крайнюю левую границу, крайнюю верхнюю) и радиус
  TextABC.Create(10,10,10,s,clRed);
// выводим эти свойства 
  Sleep(3000);
// Ждём 3 секунды
  i.Left:=300;
  i.Color:=clBlue;
// Перемещаем круг на 150 пикселей вправо и меняем его цвет на синий
end.
```